# Cant update values in mysql database php

Tags: php

I am trying to update a record on my admin mysql table. But still no changes when i try this method.. I can't see the problem wth this code..

Info.php

```
<?php
$query = "SELECT * from admin where username = '{$_SESSION['login_user']}'";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$query);

while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
    {
          echo '<input type="text" class="form-control" name="user_id" disabled value='.$row['user_id'].'>';
          echo '<input type="text" class = "form-control" name = "lastname"  value='.$row['lname'].'>';
          echo '<input type="text" class = "form-control" name = "firstname"  value='.$row['fname'].'>';
          echo '<input type="text" class = "form-control" name = "middlename"  value='.$row['mname'].'>';
          echo '<input type="text" class = "form-control" name = "address"  value='.$row['address'].'>';
          echo '<input type="text" class = "form-control" name = "contact"  value='.$row['contact'].'>';
          echo '<input type="text" class = "form-control" name = "email_add"  value='.$row['email_add'].'>';
          echo '<input type="text" class = "form-control" name = "username"  value='.$row['username'].'>';
          echo '<input type="password" class = "form-control" name = "password"  value='.$row['password'].'>';
          echo '<input type="password" class = "form-control" name = "confirmPassword" value='.$row['conf_pass'].'>';
    }?>

          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="update">Submit</button>
```

update.php ---- I don't know what's the problem with it.

```
<?php
include('pgconnect.php');
if(isset($_GET['update'])){
    $acctid = $_GET['user_id'];
    $lname = $_GET['lastname'];
    $fname = $_GET['firstname'];
    $mname = $_GET['middlename'];
    $address = $_GET['address'];
    $contact = $_GET['contact'];
    $email = $_GET['email_add'];
    $user = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['username']);    # use whatever escaping function your db requires this is very important.
    $pass = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['password']);
    $confpass = mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['confirmPassword']);
        $sql = "UPDATE admin SET lname='$lname', fname='$fname', mname ='$mname', address='$address' contact = $contact, email_add = '$email', username ='$user',password = '$pass', conf_pass = '$confpass' where user_id = '$acctid'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
            echo "$sql";
                if($result){
                    echo"Succesully Updated!";
                }
                    else
                        {
                        echo"Cannot be Updated!";
                    }
        mysqli_close($conn);
    }?>
```

Comment: u r using $acctid = $_GET['user_id']; try to replace with $_POST in all variables

Comment: So what is it doing? Is *anything* output at all? Have you tried some debugging to figure out up to what point it works?

Comment: where is your form tag?$

Comment: Is that the whole of info.php or part of it? Does update.php ever run? Are there any errors?

Comment: why do you mix mysql and mysqli functions? that won't work...

Comment: I try to update by clicking the button but there's no display.. the error doesn't show up..

Comment: @RaphaelMüller the form tag is in the first figure above..

Comment: @JamesWaddington that's not the whole part of info.php

Comment: @North22 not in your code, please add the line with `<form....`

Comment: @RaphaelMüller i forgot to put it..  <form id="defaultForm" method="post" action="dashboard.php?id=<?php echo $record['user_id'] ?>" class="form-horizontal" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Comment: @RaphaelMüller I replaced mysql -> mysqli

Comment: if you just have one result row, you don't need the while loop. if you really use the while loop, you should send an array back to the update script. with your code, you would just update the last input fields with the same names.

Comment: @North22 your formaction is dashboard.php not update.php... and the method is POST so you have to use `$_POST` in your update.php also

Comment: i changed dashboard.php -> update.php and also GET -> POST.. and then the error show up.. Notice: Undefined index: user_id in C:\xampp\htdocs\system\update.php on line 6
UPDATE admin SET lname='Obemio', fname='Gerald', mname ='G', address='Bayugan' contact = 123, email_add = 'geraldobemio@yahoo.com', username ='admin',password = 'pass', conf_pass = 'pass' where user_id = ''Cannot be Updated!

Comment: missed a comma address='$address' contact = $contact  between the fields. Also seems you need $contact within single quotes.

Comment: @Nort22 your action looks like `update.php?id=2134` and you ask for `$_GET['user_id']`. that won't work, you have to use `$_GET['id']` or rename your parameter to user_id

Answer (score 1):

To understand the mechanism behind forms:

index.html:

```
<form action="update.php?param=234" method="post">
  <input type="text" name="firstfield" />
  <button name="update">Submit</button>
</form>
```

update.php:

```
<?php

echo $_GET['param']; //should output 234
echo $_POST['firstfield']; //should output whatever you put in your textfield
var_dump($_POST['update']); //should return something
```

as you noticed, the parameter after ? in your action is passed as GET value and all the other values are POST values.

Comment: i try it but still wont work UPDATE admin SET lname='Obemio', fname='Gerald', mname ='G', address='Bayugan' contact = 123, email_add = 'geraldobemio@yahoo.com', username ='admin',password = 'pass', conf_pass = 'pass' where user_id = ''1''string(0) "" Cannot be Updated!